# counting the amount of times a number occurs in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of size 50 that holds random integers between 1 and 49.

I would like to be able to count the amount of times the numbers between 10 and 19 occur within the array.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
   var arr = [];

   function getRandom( num ){
       return Math.round(Math.random() * num)+1;
   }

   var counter = 0;

   for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
       arr.push(getRandom( 49 ));
       counter++;
   }
```

Comment: So check if the number is between 10 and 19 before incrementing the counter. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count=0;
for (var i=0;i<50;i++{
  if(arr[i]<19 && arr[i]>10){
    count++;
  }
}
```

that is if you mean 10 and 19 not to be counted if you want to count 10 and 19 also, then change the limit to 20 and 9

Comment: Or change the comparisons to `<=` and `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Arry.filter` method:

```
var nBetween10and19 = [yourArraY]
                       .filter(function(b){return b>10 && b<19;}).length;
```

[**See MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for information on `Array.filter` and a shim for older browsers

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to make a function because you can reuse it later with different parameters.

I wrote a function that accepts min and max values, and counts the number of occurrences that satifies the limits.

you can pass null for either min or max if you do not want to specify them.

```
function countRange(list, min, max) {
    var c = 0;
    for (var i = 0, l = list.length, item; i < l; i++) {
        item = list[i];
        if ((min == null || item >= min) && (max == null || item <= max)) {
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}

countRange(arr, 10, 19); // count x >= 10 and x <= 19
countRange(arr, 10, null); // count x >= 10
countRange(arr, null, 30); // count x <= 30
```